# Tenserflow.js image classifier how I can get result from server to display inside the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, tensorflow

I am a newbie in TensorFlow my code on serverside works well but I tried to return the value from the server , I got this error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined) why ? also How I can display the result on HTML page

```js
app.post("/image/classify", async (req, res) => {
  var  {url}  = req.body.Imageurl;

  return model.classify({
    imageUrl: url,
  }).then((predictions) => {
     //
      for (let i = 0; i < predictions.length; i++) {
        if(predictions[i].score>=0.8){
            console.log(predictions[i].score);
            console.log(predictions[i].class);
            document.getElementById("img").value = predictions[i].class;

            res.json({success:true, predictions:predictions[i].class});

        } 
        }
    
    //return res.json(predictions);

  }).catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
    res.json({success:false, message:'Something went wrong'+ e});
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong!")
  });
});
```

```html
 <form action="/image/classify" method="post">
          <input  name="Imageurl" >
          <button>Predict Issue</button>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input id="img">
          
        </form>
```

Comment: Did you the [Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/transfer/image_classification#:~:text=In%20this%20tutorial%2C%20you%20will,for%20image%20classification%20called%20MobileNet.) on Image classification using TF.js.

Comment: @TFer I render HTML code, hence I display the results of the prediction on a web page.  and it works well.  If you have another suggestion please share it with me?